# Best complexity to find solutions to x^2+y^2=z^2

Tags: algorithm

What is the algorithm with the best complexity that finds solutions in a given range to the equation x² + y² = z²?

x, y and z are integers and the range is about [0,10^6].

The best i could do is to iterate through all x and all 
y and store x² + y² in a hash and then iterate through all possible z and check if z² is in the hash.

Comment: @skr: We don't have mathjax here on stackoverflow...

Comment: @Chris it looks like he need a logic shorten the time complexity of the algorithm he used in the program. Andrei have mentioned hash, iteration which is related to programing.

Comment: @skr: I think you may have misunderstood what I was saying... You made an edit to the question putting `$` around various things which is mathjax. I was letting you know that mathjax wouldn't work on stack overflow. I was making no comment on the question itself, just that your edit ended up looking messy which is why I rolled it back.

Comment: Thank you for point it out @Chris. I didn't  know.

Comment: Is it a question from a coding contest ? can you post the link to the contest ? Are you really asked to compute all the triples or just to count them ?

Comment: I take it you're looking for integer solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider only x is odd and y is even.

- Solutions with x and y both even can be obtained by noticing that:

  x = 2x1; y = 2y1; z = 2z1, where x1, y1 and z1 are also a solution
- You can easily prove that if both x and y are odd then x^2+y^2 gives remainder 2 modulo 4, which can not be a perfect square.
- obviously if (x,y,z) is solution then (y,x, z) is also a solution

With this optimisation you consider 4 times less possibilities for x and y and only odd values for z (2 times less).

Comment: You can I think go a step further than x odd and y even to say they have no common factors. eg there is no point testing 9, 12 because we already know that 3,4 works. I don't know if you will spend more time working out if they have common factors than you do just testing them though... Likewise with the both even - is it less work to generate the solutions after rather than detecting them and skipping them?

Comment: @Chris - for the latter- definitely worth it. I am still trying to think how to testiterate only coprime numbers,